# Get-effective access for users in a group through folder path

Tags: powershell, scripting, migration, entity-framework-migrations, powershell-ise

using the powershell ise access control module
Here's what I'm trying:

```
$Folders = get-content ***path to local file of users
$User = "**user group name**"
foreach ($folder in $Folders){

    If(Test-Path $folder)
    {
       $exists = "File exists" 
    }
    Else{
        $exists = "File does not exists"
    }

    $permission = (Get-EffectiveAccess $Folder -Principal $User) | ?{$_.IdentityReference -match $User} | Select IdentityReference, EffectiveAccess, `
    @{Expression={$Folder}},@{Name='UNC';Expression={$exists}}

    If ($permission)
    {
        $permission | Out-File -FilePath C:\access -append 

    }
    Else{
        Write-output "$User Doesn't have any permission on $Folder" >> C:\stuff\fileaccess2.csv
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
ResolveLongPath : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PowerShellAccessControl\PowerShellAccessControlHelperFunctions.ps1:3878 char:29
+                             ResolveLongPath $CurrentPath
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ResolveLongPath], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,ResolveLongPath
```

Please help why this wouldnt work

Comment: The error message comes from a part of the script you are not showing us.. At first sight however I can see an error in the part you did post: `@{Expression={$Folder}}` The `Name=...` part is missing.

Comment: Check the values being set to the `$folder` variable. `Get-Path` throws the mentioned error when given an empty value.